# Convert WMI script to WMIC

Tags: wmi, wmi-query, wmic

How I can write below WMI Script to WMIC?

```
   strComputer = "." 
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\Microsoft\SqlServer\ComputerManagement10") 
Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery( _
    "SELECT * FROM ServerNetworkProtocol",,48) 
For Each objItem in colItems 
    Wscript.Echo "-----------------------------------"
    Wscript.Echo "ServerNetworkProtocol instance"
    Wscript.Echo "-----------------------------------"
    Wscript.Echo "Enabled: " & objItem.Enabled
    Wscript.Echo "ProtocolName: " & objItem.ProtocolName
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

**WMIC Command:** 
wmic /namespace:\\root\Microsoft\SqlServer\ComputerManagement10 path ServerNetworkProtocol get /all

```
Enabled  InstanceName  MultiIpConfigurationSupport  ProtocolDisplayName  ProtocolName
TRUE     MSSQLEXPRESS  FALSE                        Shared Memory        Sm
FALSE    MSSQLEXPRESS  FALSE                        Named Pipes          Np
FALSE    MSSQLEXPRESS  TRUE                         TCP/IP               Tcp
FALSE    MSSQLEXPRESS  FALSE                        VIA                  Via
```

**PowerShell Command:**
powershell -command "Get-WmiObject -Namespace root\Microsoft\SqlServer\ComputerManagement10 -Class ServerNetworkProtocol |Format-Table Enabled, MultiIpConfigurationSupport, ProtocolDisplayName, ProtocolName -AutoSize"

```
Enabled MultiIpConfigurationSupport ProtocolDisplayName ProtocolName
------- --------------------------- ------------------- ------------
   True                       False Shared Memory       Sm
  False                       False Named Pipes         Np    
  False                        True TCP/IP              Tcp
  False                       False VIA                 Via
```